# How do I download qt5-default for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-recommendation, qt5

I need an easy explanation because I am very new to Linux and I want to use an app that makes use of qt5 as requested by their website.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a one-liner in Terminal, but let's make sure you're updating `apt` first:

1. Update `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install qt5:

   ```
   sudo apt install qt5-default
   ```
3. There is no step 3

That should do it for you

Comment: Sometimes `sudo apt-add-repository universe` is needed to enable *universe* [pocket](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=qt5-default).