# qt5-default not in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: apt, qt, 21.04

I tried to install `qt5-default` but the package was not found. Of course, I read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320562/how-do-i-download-qt5-default-for-ubuntu-20-04-lts) and added `universe` to the apt and done a `apt update`.

I think `qt5-default` is not in 21.04 yet as it says [here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?q=qt5-default) so how can I install, i need it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The 21.04 is based on Debian bullseye, which does not have `qt5-default` package in [the repository](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=qt5-default). I reported a [bug to launchpad about missed `qt5-default` package](https://pad.lv/1926802).

There is a way is to install [all dependencies of `qt5-defalt` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/qt5-default) with

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools
```

and then try to compile your application.

---

If you are installing some package from third-party which requires `qt5-default` package on Ubuntu 21.04 (or newer), then you can create fake package by using commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install equivs

cd ~/Downloads
cat <<EOF > qt5-default-control
Package: qt5-default
Source: qtbase-opensource-src
Version: 5.99.99+fake-13ubuntu37
Architecture: all
Depends: qtbase5-dev, qtchooser
Suggests: qt5-qmake, qtbase5-dev-tools
Conflicts: qt4-default
Section: libdevel
Priority: optional
Homepage: http://qt-project.org/
Description: Qt 5 development defaults fake package
EOF

equivs-build qt5-default-control
sudo apt-get install ./qt5-default_5.99.99+fake-13ubuntu37_all.deb
```

and enjoy.

---

But IMO better way is to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS instead to live another 4 years without problems as it has needed [`qt5-default` package in place](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/qt5-default).

---

[This](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5902890.html) explains that `qt5-default` became obsolete, and that's why it was removed.

Comment: I still cant mark +1 on your answer, but is the right one

Comment: i found [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5902890.html) too, it explains that `qt5-default` became obsolete.  Maybe because Qt6 is coming out.

Comment: Thanks, looks as the reason for `qt5-default` removal.

Comment: `sudo apt install qttools5-dev-tools` for QT designer.

Comment: Worked for me on Xubuntu 21.04 Hirsute.

Comment: Worked for me on Mint 21. I had installed QTCreator and clang, but the line **#include <QApplication>** in my c++ source file caused make to fail with **fatal error: 'QApplication' file not found.** Not any more, ty!

Answer (score 7):

Two ways to solve this on Ubuntu 21.04

#### Fast hack

Packages can be installed without the `qt5-default` dependency with:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i ODADrawingsExplorer_QT5_lnxX64_7.2dll_22.5.deb
```

This will install the package. The solution is not perfect. `apt` knows the missing dependency and it will remove the package if you do an upgrade, for example. `sudo apt -f install` will remove the package. But this is ok if you just want to try the application.

#### Long term solution: change the package dependencies

This is not so easy, but it removes the `qt5-default` dependency.

I'll use the `ODADrawingsExplorer_QT5_lnxX64_7.2dll_22.5.deb` package here, but this works with any other package.

Unpack the package:

```
cd tmp/
ar -x ../ODADrawingsExplorer_QT5_lnxX64_7.2dll_22.5.deb
tar xf control.tar.xz
```

Edit `control` file and remove the `qt5-default` dependency from the `Pre-Depends` or `Depends` list.

Pack the package:

```
tar cfJ control.tar.xz control
ar rcs ../oda-without-qt-default.deb debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i oda-without-qt-default.deb
```

You can check that the dependencies are fine with `sudo apt -f install`. The package will not be removed.

Comment: Excellent, +1, I've used your "long term solution" to install the spinnaker SDK from FLIR, having installed qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake and qtbase5-dev-tools. Works perfectly. Not so complicated in fact.

Answer (score 4):

`qt5-default` was removed in the `qtbase-opensource-src` source package in Debian's version `5.15.1+dfsg-2`.  Hirsute autosynced in `5.15.2+dfsg-5` during the development cycle.

There is no way to 'return' `qt5-default` in the package without manually recompiling the package, and it looks like other things were removed since `-default` is no more.

This was the changelog justification for the removal:

> - Remove qt5-default. Nowadays it's not needed as Qt 5 is the only Qt version
>   in Debian and it brought more problems than solutions.

Installing any `.deb` files manually that depend on `qt5-default` will not function, and you will need whoever provided those `.deb` files to update them.  If the `.deb` file is from an older system, you are not going to be able to configure it to function properly because you will have to rebuild that package for newer Ubuntu, which may or may not be an option based on the age of the package you're trying to install.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [estibordo's](https://askubuntu.com/users/27753/estibordo) "[Long term solution: change the package dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335184/qt5-default-not-in-ubuntu-21-04/1349379#1349379)" I made the following script.

```shell
#!/bin/sh
read -p "[Warning] This script will modify all the debian files in the current directory. Continue (y/n)? " reply
echo 
if [ "$reply" = "y" ]; then
    for deb_file in *.deb
    do
        ar -x $deb_file
        tar -xf control.tar.gz
        sed -i 's/qt5-default, //g' control
        tar -cf control.tar.gz control
        ar -rcs $deb_file debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz
        rm control control.tar.gz data.tar.gz debian-binary md5sums shlibs
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`qt5-default` package is missing from Ubuntu 21.04 repository, so you should just install all base packages by yourself by running the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools
```

Answer from [Farshid616](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3365136/farshid616)'s [StackOwerflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67373586/install-qt5-on-ubuntu-21-04).