# apt-get cannot install qt5-default in Ubuntu virtual box installation

Tags: apt, virtualbox, qt

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS running through a Virtual Box on a Windows 10 machine.

For my project, I need to install `qt5-default`, so I run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install qt5-default`

Unfortunately I get an error:

`E: Package 'qt5-default' has no installation candidate`

I'm a bit confused, because my Ubuntu installation seems to be OK, and the qt5 [docs](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu) say nothing about this.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is there `no installation candidate`

Comment: If you want your qt apps supported you need different packages. Did you search in this [forum?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1335187/906933)

Comment: @kanehekili, sort of, but it doesn't really explain how I can get it working for Ubuntu without resorting to building everything from source...

Comment: Well, you might be more verbose then. Explain why you need that package (in your question, **not** in the comments). The qt5-default package is used to build stuff, not to run them. The qt5-default package was just a metapackage, which contained the packages in the link. So there is no difference

Comment: @kanehekili I guess in that case I don't really need the metapackage and could probably install the individual dependencies separately as shown in the link you provide

Comment: I tend to agree with the bug report that closed qt5-default missing; ie. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtbase-opensource-src/+bug/1926802  which is found in [@n0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert)'s answer